# Как реализовать индикатор получения сообщений в ActionBar?

Tags: java, android

У меня в ActionBar есть иконка в виде конверта которая и есть индикатор сообщений... Я хочу сделать так, чтоб количество непрочитанных сообщений отражалось прям рядом с иконкой конверта. Я установил иконку конверта, но как установить какое нибудь textview рядом с ним в которое можно устанавливать соответствующий номер сообщения я не знаю... или может есть какое то готовое решение как это правильно сделать...

Вот так я устанавливаю меню в коде

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

и вот так у меня написан XML файл

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:icon="@drawable/message"
    android:title="Menu"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

и вот так это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Единственный возможный вариант который я вижу в данном случае, подготовить множество иконок, у которых будет рядом с конвертом нужное число, а потом каким нибудь блоком switch возвращать нужную иконку. Боюсь что выставить некий TextView там не выйдет

Answer (score 2):

Посоветую использовать кастомный тулбар и в нем добавить компонент наследник кнопки с текстовым полем там, где тебе нужно. При таком подходе можно работать с тулбаром как с обычным `View`.

tollbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                               android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                               android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                               app:theme="@style/ShoppingListTheme">

    <!-- тут размести элемент кнопки -->

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <!-- тут, как обычно, размести внутренние элементы активити -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
    private YourCustomButton mYourCustomButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);

        mYourCustomButton = (YourCustomButton) mActionBarToolbar.findViewById(R.id.yourCustomButtonId);
    }
}
```

Далее прокидывай в кнопку `mYourCustomButton` количество сообщений и готово.

Код самой кнопки не нужен?